# How does on know that an app's code isnt the same as the public one?

Tags: malware, github, open-source

Let's say I found a cool application but i'm not sure if its malware. But everyone says don't worry its safe because its open source, but how would I know if the actual exe's code is different that the code on Github for example?

Comment: For fun or to be scared, you might want to read https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf. It won't solve your problem but clearly exposes (decades ago) that having the source code is not enough if you want formal proof the binary is safe. In fact 100% proof is almost impossible (once you looked at all software paths, you need to take into account the hardware too...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you compile it yourself using the source code available you don't.

As long as you get it from a reputable source it is very likely to be the same, but it is difficult or nearly impossible to validate. You can recompile it yourself, but there might be tiny differences in your setup that produces an executable that is subtly different so binary comparison might not be perfect either. You might, if you knew the exact compiler settings and optimisations used, get close enough to see whether large amounts of code were added but direct comparison might well need an experienced eye to tell the difference between a compiler optimisation and an intentional modification.

Open source only guarantees that the code is available for peer review, not that it wasn't modified prior to being compiled.

If the code was tampered with prior to compilation then you might be able to decompile it, but compiled executables can lack information such as human readable function and variable names that make retrieving the original source impossible.  Compilers can also optimise code in ways that make the output work the same but look wildly different making the task of comparison even more difficult.

As a couple of examples, code functions can be merged inline with the code that calls them, and loops can be "unrolled" into linear streams to avoid expensive branches in the CPU.

Open Source only means that you can take the source yourself and build it in the same way that the original author did, assuming you have access to the same tools and libraries.

Comment: I see, Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Karim2 carrying on from this many modern systems do allow for code to be digitally signed or have provided hashes at the very least. That can allow you to validate where the executable came from and that it was not modified by a third party, but still requires you to trust the place or company that you got it from.

Comment: So the phrase "Oh dont worry its not malware because its open source" isnt trustable right?

Comment: @Karim2 that particular phrasing is indeed misleading and confers some magical quality that open source is somehow immune to having malware injected into it which is not the case. Anyone can compile it and insert whatever malware they like and it comes down to where you get it from and whether they are trustworthy. Open source means only that the source is open and freely available, not that the person who compiled it is trustworthy or didn't just have a malware infection on their machine. "Open source" is not a substitute for good antivirus or malware protection.

Comment: You would trust most major companies to have stringent policies and processes to ensure that machines are free of malware while compiling and that they would act quickly to assess damage and remove affected packages or breaches if found, but it is still down to the company distributing the package in the first place. Sure you can get packages from another location, and verify against that to make sure one location alone is safe, but it is a lot of extra work for a little bit of extra safety.

Comment: That makes sense thanks a lot.